# Suppose that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. What is $U+U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. What is $U+U$?

Why does $U+U = U?$ I want to think of this geometrically, say in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$  we have some random plane in space that intersects the origin. How is this subspace, when added to itself, equal to itself?

Comment: I am not sure what this notion of 'addition' means. How does one add one vector space to another?

Comment: Just add the elements (vectors).

Comment: I would assume it is $\{ x+y \ | \ x \in U, \ y \in U \}$ which is clearly $U$ again here.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook This makes sense, but then the result follows directly from the definition of a subspace.

Comment: yes. the problem is trivial.

Comment: @Kevin Driscoll to be clear, trivial in the sense of linear algebra. Perhaps not trivial in terms of geometry, the beauty of linear algebra is manifest in the wealth of cases this proposition covers (see answer by Clive Newstead and discussion by MJD).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$U+U$ is the subset of $V$ consisting of everything that you can possibly get when you add two elements of $U$ to each other. Since $U$ is a subspace, adding any two of its elements lands you back in the subspace, so you get $U+U \subseteq U$. Conversely, $u=u+0$ for all $u \in U$, and so $U \subseteq U+U$.

In general, given subspaces $U, W \le V$, the sum $U+W$ is what you can possibly obtain by adding a vector in $U$ and a vector in $W$. Geometrically thinking, you can imagine dragging $U$ along $W$, then $U+W$ is the space it fills up.

For instance, if $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are two different lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\ell_1 + \ell_2$ is the (unique) plane containing both lines. Why? Because if you drag one line along another line, the space it sweeps out is a plane.

Comment: This answer is excellent, thank you

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer, but that you missed the opportunity to point out here that if $\ell_1 = \ell_2$, then $\ell_1 + \ell_2$ is what you get if you drag $\ell_1$ along *itself*, and this is exactly $\ell_1$ again.

Comment: Thanks for that addition MJD